# UWP Scale ellipse smoothly?

Tags: uwp

Hi I have a use case where the user should able to scale ellipse by selecting a stroke(border) of the ellipse.I have tried using Pointer Pressed and Pointermove event of shape to achieve this. But Scaling is not continuous(smooth). Anyone have an idea of how to better way achieve this That will help a lot thanks

```
private void PostureDifficultyPath_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Path selectedPath = sender as Path;
        if (selectedPath != null)
        {
            selectedPath.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkBlue);
            PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(selectedPath);
            mousePressedPoint = new Point(ptrPt.Position.X, ptrPt.Position.Y);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
private void PostureDifficultyPath_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;
        double mouseCurrentPosition;
        if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(DifficultyUpperPath);
            if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
            {//this is a variable which i update using mvvm
               //this scale factor should be like a value which makes smooth scaling
                ScaleFactor -= 0.1111411;//
            }
            else { mouseCurrentPosition= ptrPt.Position.X; }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }


 <Path>
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure  x:Name="UpperCircle" StartPoint="{x:Bind UpperStartPoint,Mode=TwoWay }">
                        <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" x:Name="UpperArc"
                            Size="{x:Bind UpperArcRadius,Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Point="{x:Bind UpperArcEndPoint,Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform 
                                 CenterX="125" CenterY="100"   
                                 ScaleX="{x:Bind ScaleFactor,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 ScaleY="{x:Bind ScaleFactor,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
```

Comment: show your code?

Comment: Hi Muzib i have added code too

Comment: I don't understand how the Scale of the Ellipse is changed by that `ScaleFactor` and what do you mean by *smooth scaling*. Let me guess, to make the points less discrete, did you try to get the intermediate points between mouse move event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint.getintermediatepoints#Windows_UI_Input_PointerPoint_GetIntermediatePoints_System_UInt32_

Comment: I have ellipse geometry in path data which should scale increase or decrease Which i am managing by the scale factor .Kindly see updated question

Comment: it's an `EllipseGeometry` inside `Path`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the path data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Storyboard` to smooth your Scale transform.

**xaml**

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ScaleStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="ScaleXAnimation" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="CompositeTransform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="ScaleYAnimation" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="CompositeTransform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

...

<Path>
    ...
   <Path.RenderTransform>
       <ScaleTransform 
                    CenterX="125" CenterY="100"   
                    x:Name="EllipseScaleTransform"/>
   </Path.RenderTransform>
    ...
</Path>

...
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
private void PostureDifficultyPath_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // other code
    ScaleXAnimation.To = ScaleYAnimation.To = MyScale;
    ScaleStoryboard.Begin();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Best regards.